# Capture parameter from URL and set in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Stocks</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Slider main container -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->

        <!-- Slide 1 -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="widget-container">
            <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
              <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
              <script
                type="text/javascript"
                src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js"
                async
              >

                {
                  "symbol": "BSE:INFY",
                  "width": "100%",
                  "locale": "in",
                  "colorTheme": "light",
                  "isTransparent": false
                }
              </script>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>

    <script></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to pass `"symbol": "BSE:INFY"` through URL like -- http://example.com?symbol=BSE:INFY OR http://example.com?symbol=BSE:APLAPOLLO

The text which I pass in `symbol` in URL, it should get replaced in HTML code -- `"symbol": "BSE:INFY"`

How can I pass symbol through URL, capture it and set in HTML above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are too late if the script is reading the parameters from the embedded script. You would need to do something like this

Remember to change my demo string

```
const usp = new URLSearchParams("?symbol=BSE:INFY")
```

to

```
const usp = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
```

on your page

```html
<div class="widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  const usp = new URLSearchParams("?symbol=BSE:APLAPOLLO") // new URLSearchParams(location.search); // on your page
  document.write(`<script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js">{"symbol": "${usp.get("symbol")}", "width": "100%","locale": "in", "colorTheme": "light", "isTransparent": false }<\/script>`)
</script>
```

This does not work because the script does not like the object inside the script tags.

That is a shame because it is better code.

```html
<div class="widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  const usp = new URLSearchParams("?symbol=BSE:INFY") // new URLSearchParams(location.search); // on your page
  const scr = document.createElement("script");
  scr.innerText = `{"symbol": "${usp.get("symbol")}", "width": "100%","locale": "in", "colorTheme": "light", "isTransparent": false }`
  document.querySelector("head").appendChild(scr);                        
  scr.src = "https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js"

</script>
```

Comment: can you please give me the full html to make this work?

Comment: How to pass the symbol dynamically? It always shows Infosys now.

Comment: change

`const usp = new URLSearchParams("?symbol=BSE:INFY") `
to
`const usp = new URLSearchParams(location.search);`
on your page

Comment: You can remove `const scr = document.createElement("script");` that was a leftover from my other try

Answer (score 1):

**If you can do it on PHP(serverside) do below**

If you use these links 
http://example.com?symbol=BSE:INFY
http://example.com?symbol=BSE:APLAPOLLO

You can access the symbol variable as get request on serverside
so that you can use it as below

```
            {
              "symbol": "<?php echo $_GET['symbol'];?>",
              "width": "100%",
              "locale": "in",
              "colorTheme": "light",
              "isTransparent": false
            }
```

**If not, Use URL Hash(Client side HTML and JS only)**

This will be your links:
 http://example.com#BSE:APLAPOLLO
 http://example.com#BSE:INFY

then in your script you will use

```
        {
          "symbol": window.location.hash.substring(1),
          "width": "100%",
          "locale": "in",
          "colorTheme": "light",
          "isTransparent": false
        }
```

Comment: I don't want to use php.

Comment: if then,

you can use url hash

Comment: This will be your link:
 http://example.com#BSE:INFY

then in your script you will use

            {
              "symbol": window.location.hash.substring(1),
              "width": "100%",
              "locale": "in",
              "colorTheme": "light",
              "isTransparent": false
            }

Comment: @JovylleBermudez That will not work The script reads the innerText of the script when it is loading

Comment: Please again the Answer,
i edited it if you cant use PHP @dang

Comment: What does shows?
it works on my end, i can get BSE:INFY effeciently on Client side only

by using
window.location.hash.substring(1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript apis:

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
const symbol = queryParams.get('symbol')
```

Comment: Can you give me the full HTML and where to place this code?